# Find most common number combinations in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, numbers

I'm new in this forum but after browsing through several posts similar to what I'm searching I decided to post one myself since the ones already posted apparently don't work for my problem. If, however, there is a code posted that could work for my case please do let me know what I should change to make it work and apologies, I'm new to this..

I have a worksheet with sets of numbers ranging from 1 to 90, with each row having 5 random numbers ex: 23 34 56 02 10

What I would like to be able to find in Excel is the most common combinations of 3 or 4 numbers in the multiple rows I have, here's an ex:

23 34 56 02 10

10 52 34 23 02

56 02 10 22 33

42 05 08 76 51

23 56 02 10 15

88 86 56 10 03

and so on...meaning that the most common 4 number combination in this short example is 23 56 02 10

Based on this of course the data I have to analyze goes on and on always with sets of five but reaching over 1000 rows.

Is there a code I can implent in VBA or a formula I can use to help me figure out how often the same numbers appear together in each row?

I've done this independently with numbers using a histogram but now I would like to see the nummber of combinations where similar numbers do appear together.

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm a bit of a novice so if you could explain it step by step what I have to do it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Results will be paste in Sheet 2 sorted. The reason why a choice to show all the values is because in many cases you have numbers with the same number of repetitions. Lastly i think you make a mistake because the four numbers with more repetitions are 23, 34, 56, 2.

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowS1A As Long, LastRowS2A As Long, Times As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String

    LastRowS1A = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRowS1A

        str1 = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("C" & i).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("D" & i).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("E" & i).Value

        LastRowS2A = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A1:A" & LastRowS2A), str1) = 0 Then

            Times = 1

            For y = i + 1 To LastRowS1A

                str2 = Sheet1.Range("A" & y).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("B" & y).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("C" & y).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("D" & y).Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("E" & y).Value

                If str1 = str2 Then
                    Times = Times + 1
                End If

            Next y

            Sheet2.Range("A" & LastRowS2A + 1).Value = str1
            Sheet2.Range("B" & LastRowS2A + 1).Value = Times

        End If

    Next i


    LastRowS2A = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Sheet2.Range("A2:B" & LastRowS2A).Sort Key1:=Sheet2.Range("B1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
```

End Sub

**Sheet 1:**

[image]

**Sheet 2**:

[image]

Comment: Right I understand what you did there unfortunately what I'm looking for are 4 equal numbers in the same line all together, what you mentioned above I am aware how to do it and that's with pivotal or histogram which shows how many times the same numbers comes up, however what I'm looking for is having the same combination of numbers on the same line hence why I said 23 56 02 10, which comes up 2 times out of 5, meanwhile the others don't come up together as often.

Comment: But the combination "23 56 02 10" only exists in your example once - as other examples have extra numbers in them so they don't match... such as "23 **34** 56 02 10"  So, the combination of "56 02 10" is the most common, not what you suggested.

Comment: @LucaMastroianno there was a misunderstanding. In each row, all numbers appears in the same cell or in five different cells (5 different columns)?

Comment: There's 5 numbers in five different cells but each set of 5 is in one row, it doesn't matter @solar mike if there's a number in between since I am unable to control that, it's an input of data that is not dependable of me, but what I am searching for whether those numbers are present, doesn't matter if they are all 4 together, the important thing to find out is If they are there. In my example there's 6 rows and in the 1st and 5th row the set 23 56 10 02 appear in the same row. I found a similar post with names of colors but when I tried to use it in my case it didnt work out.

Comment: Thank you @Error1004 will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_Columns_G_to_Q()
    Range("G:Q").Delete
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Sub Main_without_Sort()

    'uncomment if you want to write sample data
    'Call SampleData

    CreateNumbers
    CopyResults
    CreatePivot

End Sub

Sub Main_including_Sort()

    'uncomment if you want to write sample data
    'Call SampleData

    SortEverySingleRow_by_Column
    CreateNumbers
    CopyResults
    CreatePivot

End Sub

Sub SampleData()

Dim a(10) As String
Dim b() As String
Dim numParts As Integer
Dim iCt As Integer
Dim jCt As Integer

a(1) = "23 34 56 02 10"
a(2) = "10 52 34 23 02"
a(3) = "56 02 10 22 33"
a(4) = "42 05 08 76 51"
a(5) = "23 56 02 10 15"
a(6) = "88 86 56 10 03"

With Range("A:F")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

For iCt = 1 To 6
    b = Split(a(iCt), " ")
    numParts = UBound(b) + 1
    Range(Cells(iCt, 1), Cells(iCt, numParts)).Value = b
    For jCt = 1 To 5
        Cells(iCt, jCt).Value = Cells(iCt, jCt).Value
        Debug.Print Cells(iCt, jCt).Address
    Next jCt
Next iCt
End Sub

Sub SortEverySingleRow_by_Column()
Dim iCt As Integer
Dim sortRange As Range

For iCt = 1 To 6
    Set sortRange = Range("A1:E1")
    If iCt > 1 Then
        Set sortRange = Range("A1:E1").Offset(iCt - 1, 0)
    End If
    'Debug.Print sortRange.Address
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=sortRange, _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange sortRange
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next iCt

End Sub

Sub CreateNumbers()

Dim iCt As Integer
Dim jCt As Integer

With Columns("G:M")
    .ColumnWidth = 13
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

For iCt = 0 To 5
    Range("G1").Offset(iCt, 0).Select
    Call CreateFormulas
Next iCt

End Sub


Sub CreateFormulas()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TEXT(RC[-6],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-5],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-4],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-3],""00"")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TEXT(RC[-7],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-6],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-5],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-3],""00"")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TEXT(RC[-8],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-7],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-5],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-4],""00"")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TEXT(RC[-9],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-7],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-6],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-5],""00"")"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=TEXT(RC[-9],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-8],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-7],""00"")& "" "" & TEXT(RC[-6],""00"")"
End Sub

Sub CopyResults()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim colCt As Integer

    lastRow = Range("G1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    'Debug.Print lastRow

    Range("M1").Value = "RESULTS"

    For colCt = 1 To 5
        Range("F1:F" & lastRow).Offset(0, colCt).Copy
        'Debug.Print Range("F1:F" & lastRow).Offset(0, colCt).Address
        Range("M2").Offset(lastRow * (colCt - 1), 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Range("M2").Offset(lastRow * (colCt - 1), 1).Value = "colCt = " & colCt
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next colCt

    Range("N1").Select
End Sub

Sub CreatePivot()

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        Range("M1").CurrentRegion, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet1!R1C15", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(1, 15).Select
    Range("P5").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("RESULTS")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable1").PivotFields("RESULTS"), "Sum of RESULTS", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of RESULTS")
        .Caption = "Count of RESULTS"
        .Function = xlCount
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("RESULTS").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Count of RESULTS", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
        PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1
    Range("G1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("RESULTS")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
End Sub
```